# Repository find in Hibernate EventListener causes stackoverflow

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a custom Hibernate event listener. If an entity is dirty the code tries to find old audit entries for that entity. The problem is that it causes a stackoverflow error.

This is my listener:

```
@Component
public class MyCustomEventListener implements FlushEntityEventListener {

    @Autowired
    private AuditService service;

    @Override
    public void onFlushEntity(FlushEntityEvent event) throws HibernateException {

        final Object entity = event.getEntity();

        boolean isDirty = isDirty(event);

        if (isDirty) {
            service.auditEntity(entity);
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And my service:

```
@Service
public class AuditServiceImpl implements AuditService
    public void auditEntity(BaseEntity entity) {    
        try {
            String tableName = getTableName(entity);
            Optional<AuditRecord> result = auditRepository.findFirstByTableNameAndRecordIdOrderByIdDesc(tableName, entity.getId());
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

During calling the repository finder it somehow triggers the eventListener again.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem too, and I only found this question. So I decided to write a solution to help people who get the same issue.

##### Why does it happen?

When you try to select some data, and you have the

Hibernate FlushMode = AUTO 
or 
Hibernate FlushMode = ALWAYS

Hibernate checks if there are active transactions that can affect the result of the selection. And if it finds any, it will try to flush the transactions, so you would get actual data from your selection.

And when it is flushing, hibernate executes all event listeners that make recursion which throws a StackOverflow

##### Solutions

1. Use a StatelessSession for selection:

```
    @Override
    public void onFlush(FlushEvent flushEvent) throws HibernateException {
        StatelessSession statelessSession = flushEvent.getSession().getSessionFactory().openStatelessSession();
        statelessSession.getTransaction().begin();
        AuditRecord auditRecord = statelessSession.createQuery("*your select here*").getSingleResult();
        statelessSession.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

2. Change the Hibernate FlushMode to COMMIT in your application.yml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      org.hibernate.flushMode: COMMIT
```